# formatting a variable as a link within infowindow on map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

OK, I can get the infowindow to pop up and it displays my link( which is actually called "address" )
However I cant get this to display as a link within the infowindow.
I've tried placing   around the address field to no avail.
The data is obviously getting into the info window I just can't make it a link ?

```
downloadUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))
        );

        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + "address"; x x x x x x x x 
        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
        });
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If variable `address` contains the link reference then you can change the following line

```
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + "address";
```

to

```
var html = "<strong><a href='" + address + "'>" + name + "</a></strong>";
```

which will make something like

```
<strong><a href='http://someLink'>Some name</a></strong>
```

So, clicking on the `Some name` will point to the link in `href` property.

or my be you want this

```
var html = "<strong>" + name + "</strong> <a href='" + address + "'>address</a>";
```

Comment: You have made my day much shorter, THANKYOU very much Sheikh